# I can't reboot my Lightsail instance Error RebootInstance[ap-southeast-1]

Tags: instance

[image]

When I press reboot the server This notification will appear. And when you press stop, it will come back to you to press stop again. Can't press stop to stop.

How can I fix this problem? OR How to reboot server?